# A Function Continous on [a,b]

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

After much research and even checking on here I was only able to find the maximum value on [a,b].

I need assistance in the following:

Prove: A function is continuous $[a,b]$ attains a minimum value on $[a,b]$

Not using sequences and compact sets

I have searched and the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem#Proving_the_theorems provides only a sequence for the minimum.

For Maximum:

$f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ therefore

$f(x)$ is bound on $[a,b]$. Let little $m$ and big $M$ denote respectively the greatest lower bound and the least upper bound of $f(x)$ on $[a,b]$

We have better show that for some $x_0,f(x_0)=M$

I suppose not: i.e suppose for $f(x)<M$ on $[a,b]$

Let $g(x)= 1/$(M-$f(x))$ on $[a,b]$. Then $g(x)>0$ on $[a,b]$ and continuous on $[a,b]$

Then $g(x)$ has a least upper bound on $[a,b]$, call it $A$.

*Notice $A>0$, so 1/$(M-$f(x))$ \le A$ then

$\frac 1A$ $\le M-f(x)$

$f(x)\le M - \frac 1A \lt M$ (oops!contradicts)

This says $M-\frac 1A$ is an upper bound and for $f(x)$ and $M$ was the least upper bound.

My confusion comes about with the minimum having to prove it using a very similar set up.

My thoughts are either following same proof just with little m, or $-f(x)$ or both. But I am stuck with not being able to use sequences.

I think I figured away out need some verification:

Let little $m$ denote the minimum

$\frac {1}{f(x)-m} \lt \epsilon$

this implies that $f(x)$ is less than little $m$ however contradicts the boundness theorem....Am I on the right track?

Comment: If you have a way to find the maximum of a continuous function (as you say in the first line), just negate the function and find the maximum; then negate the answer again.

Comment: Exact duplicate of the recent put-on-hold: [Prove the following statement about continuous function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2030756/prove-the-following-statement-about-continuous-function).

Comment: If you have a proof that the maximum value is attained, think about what you did for that proof. Whatever it was, you should be able to do the "same" thing, but "upside-down," to show that the minimum is attained. Perhaps editing your question by writing out the "maximum value" proof would help. At least it would serve to make this question _not_ a duplicate of the earlier question, which did not offer any proof of anything.

Comment: It is not true for rationals: consider $f(x)=(x^2-2)^2$ on $[0,2]$.  So what property of the real numbers are you planning to use which does not involve sequences?

Comment: @DavidK editing now with the maximum.

Comment: Now that we have a specific proof (for a related property) to consider, I think it should be possible to give a useful answer that isn't just doing the homework, and the question is certainly not a duplicate of the other linked question.

Comment: @DavidK I added a possible answer mind taking a look at it?

Comment: The proof you gave for the minimum is right (but I think you meant $f(x)$ is more than $m$ at the end) : $\frac{1}{f(x)-m}$ has a positive least upper bound $\epsilon$ as you stated, i.e. $\frac{1}{f(x)-m} \leq \epsilon$. Therefore $f(x) - m \geq \frac{1}{\epsilon} \iff f(x) \geq \frac{1}{\epsilon} + m \gt m$, so $m$ was not the greatest lower bound : contradiction. By the way, the fact that $f$ is bounded on $[a, b]$ is proved using sequences and compactness so you are indirectly using them in some way.

Comment: @Desura I appreciate the support in help solving this, but unfortunately I am still not correct. Professor stated I made epsilon a max. Or something along those lines. Ill increase the bounty to see if anyone can help.

Comment: @Brian M. Scott seing how you helped in a very similar problem(http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/226898/proof-of-the-extreme-value-theorem-without-using-subsequences) any idea if the route I am taking is a good 1 or if the poster below proof holds as I have accepted it but looked closer at it and need more clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can proceed as follows:

Show that for some $x_1,f(x_1)=m$.

Suppose not, i.e suppose $f(x)\gt m$ for $x\in[a,b]$.

Let $g(x)=\dfrac{1}{m-f(x)}$ on $[a,b]$.

Then $g(x)\lt 0$ and continuous on $[a,b]$.

Then $g(x)$ has a greatest lower bound on $[a,b]$, call it $B$.

And so $\dfrac{1}{m−f(x)}\ge B$.

But then $\dfrac1B\ge m-f(x)$, as both $B,\dfrac1{m-f(x)}\lt0$

and so $f(x)\ge m-\dfrac1B$.

This says $m-\dfrac1B$ is a lower bound for $f(x)$, however $m$ was the greatest lower bound, which is a contradiction as $m-\dfrac1B\gt m$ ($B$ is negative).

Comment: How are you concluding that B, and 1/m-f(x) are less than 0? just need a bit of clarity on that.

Comment: @ELO; because g<0